# Return Entity Object instead of String in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am developing a web portal using Freemarker(FTL) as front end technology. The complete project is based on single ftl page and have used wizard to process different kind of user request.In Back end I have used Spring MVC pattern where controller will process user request.I am using AJAX call to navigate on wizard and display data on screen.

On click button a java script function is called which further uses ajax to call controller method . The controller method perform some business logic and returns desired data.

Now My requirement is to display ajax call data in particular division of FTL page. I am using @ResponseBody to return JSON respose to ajax call.

I am using below ajax method as of now to load data in particular division of my screen.However Here I need write HTML tags in Java script section in order to  load content. But I do not want to write HTML tags in this Ajax call section. I want to return Object from ajax call and use proper FTL tags on required division to get and load data. 
Being very specific -  $("#result").html(respContent); part is giving me option to return a HTML page. But i want to return a Object/Entity which can be parsed in FTL tags.

Many Thanks in Advance

```
       $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        cache:false,
        url : "home",
        data : {},
        success : function(mwaCatlogueProfile) {
            alert('data : '+ mwaCatlogueProfile);
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", mwaCatlogueProfile);

            var respContent = "";
            respContent += "<span class='success'> <b>Please find server list:</b>";
            respContent += " </br>";
            respContent += mwaCatlogueProfile.environment + "</span>";

            $("#result").html(respContent);
            wizard.show();
        },
```

Comment: In precise - "I am using below ajax method as of now to load data in particular division of my screen.However Here I need write HTML tags in Java script section in order to load content. But I do not want to write HTML tags in this Ajax call section. I want to return Object from ajax call and use proper FTL tags on required division to get and load data. Being very specific - $("#result").html(respContent); part is giving me option to return a HTML page. But i want to return a Object/Entity which can be parsed in FTL tags."

Answer (score 0):

As FreeMarker is a server-side technology, the AJAX method had to return HTML that was rendered with FreeMarker on the server-side. So all your templates remain on the server side, only some is used in normal responses, and some in AJAX responses. Of course, if the AJAX service called is not specialized on serving your UI, then this won't work, and you have to look for a JavaScript template engine.